# phaser.io overlap colliders for a figth game style mortal kombat or the kind of games

Tags: phaser-framework

Is possible with phaser.io detect collisions overlap on transparent sprites?
something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it is. Here is an example Code with a small workaround:

http://shin.cl/pixelperfect/main.js

The other option is to set a pretty accurate polygon. There are different tools for that, but i could get pretty nasty with scaling if you are not using box2d.

With kind regards,
SirSandmann

Comment: And for your researches, it is called pixel perfect collision what you mean and for phaser questions i recommend you this forum http://www.html5gamedevs.com/ :)